# Write query for positive value in ascending order and negative value in

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql table that looks like  below :
[image]

In this table there are minus and plus value. I wants all record in dropdown in a format like.

I need to show first as **zero** than **minus value** in **descending order** and **positive value** in **acsending order**. So what query should I have to write?

For example :

```
0.00
-1
-2
 ...
 ...
 ...
 1
 2
 3
 ...
 ...
 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 3 querys and join the results together by using `union`

```
(select * from sph where value = 0)
union
(select * from sph where value < 0 order by value desc)
union
(select * from sph where value > 0 order by value asc)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```sql
ORDER BY CASE 
            WHEN Value = 0 THEN 0
            WHEN Value < 0 THEN 1 
            ELSE 2
         END ASC,          
         ABS(Value) ASC
```

The first part of the `ORDER BY` places `0` value first, followed by negative values, followed by positive values. The second part orders negative values in descending order and positive values in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from sph order by abs( `value` ) asc
```

simple ;)